# Grails integration test cannot invoke method on null service object?

Tags: grails, service, nullpointerexception, integration

Simple service class, AnalyzerService, calls stored proc in a database.
Attempting to run integration test to ensure service calls the stored proc and correct data is returned after analyzer class operates on it.  However, getting the dreaded exception that "Cannot invoke method calculateEstimateNumberOfPositions() on null object". Why is the service object null? What am I missing?

THANK YOU!

```
package foobar.analyze
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.*
import foobar.analyze.AnalyzerService
//@TestFor(AnalyzerService)
class AnalyzerServiceTests {
    def AnalyzerService service
    def dataSource

    @Before
    void setUp() {    }

    @After
    void tearDown() {   }

    @Test
    void testcalculateEstimateNumberOfPositions() {
        String positionName = "crew"
        String city = "Great Neck"
        String state = "NY"
        int numberOfPositionsSought = 100
        int expectedNumberOfPositionsEstimate = 100
        def numberOfPositionsEstimate = service.calculateEstimateNumberOfPositions(positionName, city, state, numberOfPositionsSought)
        fail (numberOfPositionsEstimate != expectedNumberOfPositionsEstimate)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convention. Stick to the convention. Anything out of convention, regarding nomenclature, will create problem during dependency injection.

Convention is to use the service class name as `analyzerService` instead of `service` in integration test.

The integration test should look like

```
class AnalyzerServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    //Service class injected only if you 
    //use the naming convention as below for AnalyzerService  
    def analyzerService 
    def dataSource
    ......
    ......
}
```

It was possible to use `service` in unit test case when you use the test mixin

`@TestFor(AnalyzerService)`

By using the above in unit test cases, you could use the default `service` variable in the test cases. This is not the same in case of integration tests.

Comment: You're right in this case that the convention is important, but the general statement that "Anything out of convention will leave you in wild" is far too strong. There are many cases when you want to go around conventions when the standard approach doesn't work for you. Just not in this case :)

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Rightly said, thanks. I got that because I am parenting my 10 months old and I am only half way through your book. :P I will update it to something reasonable.

Comment: Thank you! Yes in one of our other projects we are using service in our unit tests. Speaking of 10MO, I am just returning back from maternity leave after same amount of time - trying to re-wrap my head around grails.